# Explanation about $ \int_{- \infty}^{0} { x^n \, e^x dx} = \int_{0}^{+ \infty} { x^n \, e^{-x} dx}$

Tags: integration, education

I'm wondering how come the following equality is right? I know the property of the integral $\int_a^b=-\int_b^a$, but the below one is new for me.

$$
\int_{- \infty}^{0} { x^n \, e^x dx} =
\int_{0}^{+ \infty} { x^n \, e^{-x} dx}
$$

---

EDIT: $n$ is even.

Comment: $n$ must be even for this to be right.

Comment: Since $+\infty\ne-\infty$, a different result is used here, namely the [substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_substitution#Definite_integrals) $u=-x$ (except $u$ is renamed $x$ on the right hand side of the equation, making this less obvious). But @TheSilverDoe is right; there should also be a $(-1)^n$ factor on one side. Edit: your $n$-is-even clarification addresses this.

Comment: Thank you to all of you, now it's clear.

Answer (score 0):

A sufficient, but not necessary, condition for the following equation to be true $\int_{- \infty}^{0} {g(x) dx} =
\int_{0}^{+ \infty} {f(x) dx}$ is that $f(x)=g(-x) \quad if \; x>0 \quad$. Therefore, we could try to prove that $if \; x >0 \quad x^ne^{-x} = ({-x})^ne^{-x}$. After applying some reductions we get $$if \; x >0 \quad x^ne^{-x} = (-1)^{n}({x}^ne^{-x})$$ which is true for all n even. If you want it to be true for all n,  you have to multiply for $(-1)^n$ one member of the equation.

Comment: In fact the equality holds for even, not for odd $n$.

Comment: @user thank you